# Cakephp 4 Form Helper: Create Individual dropdown for day, month and year

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

So, in CakePHP 3, to get something like this:

[image: date month and year dropdown]

I would do this:

```
 <?= $this->Form->date('dob', [
   'templates' => ['inputContainer' => '{{content}}'], 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'minYear' => 1940, 'maxYear' => date('Y') - 5,
   'empty' => [
      'year' => "Year", // The year select control has no option for empty value
      'month' => 'Month', // The month select control does, though
      'day' => 'Day', // The month select control does, though
   ],
 ]) ?>
```

However, if I try to do the same thing on Cakephp 4, I get this

[image]

I've gone through the docs here: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-date-time-related-controls and https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html

Please how can I achieve same Cakephp 3 output on Cakephp 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
'type' => 'select'
```

as documented?
Otherwise a custom template might help.

Alternatively, the dropdown default part was moved to [Shim](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-shim) plugin
See https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-shim/blob/master/docs/View/Form.md
That should give you the 3.x way of creating such form elements.

Comment: Yes I did try 'type'=>'select' and I'm using the same date column type on my database

Comment: You could create your own template here. I am sure you look into [this](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/bootstrap-ui) and see how this can be done.